# Redirect to webroot index.php for all incoming requests

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following directory structure:

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/subfolder1/.htaccess
/subfolder1/index.php
/subfolder2/.htaccess
/subfolder2/index.php
```

I'd like all requests to be redirected to /index.php. I would like to acheive this by making some changes in /.htaccess file.

```
e.g. /abc to be rewritten to /index.php
e.g. /subfolder1/index.php to be rewritten to /index.php
```

How can I do this using webroot/.htaccess file ?

I want to do this because, I want to show a message like 'website down for maintenance' message on /index.php. I want to do this for all the subfolders on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a subfolder exists, the .htaccess in the root will not be effective.
What I mean, it will find that folder and do no rewriting.

Perhaps you can find the answer in this question:
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235054/how-to-redirect-all-www-traffic-with-htaccess-to-equal-non-www-pages?rq=1)